# Как организовать недопуск повторяющихся записей?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица:

```
(
     RECORD_ID int IDENTITY -- номер записи
    ,AREA_ID nvarchar(50) NOT NULL -- код участа
    ,[YEAR] int NOT NULL -- год запланированных работ
    ,[MONTH] int NOT NULL -- месяц запланированных работ
    ,WORK_TYPE_ID int NOT NULL -- тип запланированных работ
    ,AMOUNT float NOT NULL -- количество запланированных  работ в ед.изменения

);
```

Операторы заполняют её согласно плану предприятия.
У меня трудности с организацией уникальности записей
Суть в том что если внесена запись по определенному типу работ в определнные год и месяц, нужно запретить повторный ввод.

Мне в голову приходит создание составного первичного ключа, включающего AREA_ID, YEAR, MONTH, WORK_TYPE_ID.
Либо написание триггера на обработку вставки, но в мс сервере нет аргумента BEFORE.
Есть еще вариант через буферную таблицу, но полагаю что есть вариант проще.

Comment: а чем вас не устраивает комбинированный уникальный индекс? (какая именно SQL? [MS](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-unique-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15)?)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, честно говоря полагал, что индексы предназначены исключительно для ускорения и оптимизации поиска. Да SQL Server MS

Comment: А это и есть ускорение, ускорение проверки на уникальность при вставках \ изменениях, но никто не запрещает использовать этот же индекс и для выборки данных :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков то есть я просто могу добавить индекс составной и не будет возможности внести идентичную строку?

Comment: составной уникальный, ключевое что он уникальный, тогда он не будет являться PK, но будет вести при вставках дублей себя таким же образом как PK(primary key), причем в отличии от PK уникальных индексов может быть несколько :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, действительно работает. Оформите пожалуйста как ответ.

Comment: Путаница возникает из-за того, что правильней говорить, что нужно создать unique constraint, т.е. ограничение уникальности. А оно обычно реализовано как уникальный индекс, но это именно что деталь реализации, вас как пользователя интересует именно ограничение, а не то, что это индекс и может быть (а может и не быть) использован самой БД для ускорения поиска.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, майкософт справка говорит - "Создание ограничения уникальности автоматически приводит к созданию соответствующего уникального индекса." Так что полагаю что это равносильно.

Answer (score 0):

> Мне в голову приходит создание составного первичного ключа

Вам нужен не первичный, а альтернативный ключ. В SQL они реализуются через `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`.

Насколько я помню, в MS SQL он реализуется специальным автогенерируемым системным триггером, и не обязан иметь индекс. Хотя если в таблице записей больше сотни, то индекс желателен.